# How to deal with array of objects? I have an array with 3 objects containing JSON data from my db

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Basically, I have an array of `posts` that contains 3 objects: posts[{},{},{}]

Each object looks something like this:

```
1: Object
__v: 0
_id: "5686e17fc64feafd4486f22c"
created_at: "2016-01-01T20:28:47.889Z"
image: "Test"
message: "Test"
title: "Test Post 1"
updated_at: "2016-01-01T20:28:47.889Z"
```

I'm wondering how I can get an index or something of each object, but also use that for the object's properties.

I was testing earlier with an object of objects, and all I had to do there was: `Object.keys(this.props.data).map(this.renderPostTile)`.  Then I could just use a parameter for `renderPostTile(key)`.

How can I do something similar when I have an array of objects?

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  However, how can I do something similar to Object.keys(data).map(someFunction)?  I am trying to render a <p> with the titles, but not sure how I can do that.

Comment: `posts.map(function(post) {...})`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that, it says .map is not a function.  Here's what I am doing:  `{postData.map(this.renderTitle)}`  Above I have defined postData as this.props.data.

Comment: Why are you calling it on "postData" when you say your array is named "posts"? And why are you wrapping it with curly brackets? It's just a function call. `posts.map(this.renderTitle);`

Comment: sorry I have a `var postData = this.props.posts` sorry for the confusion

Comment: yes im trying to learn react :(

Comment: i updated above with console.log(this.props.posts) if that helps :(

Comment: Your question regarding iterating over an array of objects has been answered, sounds like you might have to start a new question with all the react stuff in as it looks like there are a couple of issues there.

Comment: Basically, what Matt says ^^ I did add a simple React example to my answer. Maybe that'll help?

Comment: Sure.  Thank you Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var posts = [
  { title: "Test Post 1" },
  { title: "Test Post 2" },
  { title: "Test Post 3" }
];

posts.map(function(post){
  var p = document.createElement("p"),
      t = document.createTextNode(post.title);
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

Obviously your objects are more complicated, but you get the idea.

**Edit:**

React-wise, you could do something like this:

```
var PostListRender = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map(function(post){
          return <li>{post.title}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

var posts = [
  {title: "Test Post 1"}, 
  {title: "Test Post 2"}, 
  {title: "Test Post 3"}
];

var el = document.getElementById('post-container');
React.render( < PostListRender posts = {posts} />, el);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVRmRW?editors=101)

Comment: Thanks Jack.  However, here is the issue.  I am doing the following:  `renderPostTile(key) {
    return (
      <PostTile key={key} index={key} postData={this.props.posts[key]} />
    );
  }

  render() {
      var postData = this.props.posts;
      return (
          <div className="container">              
            <div className="row">
              {postData.map(this.renderPostTile)}       
            </div>
          </div>
      );
  }`  Unfortunately, I get an error saying `TypeError: postData.map is not a function`

Comment: oh god.  how do I edit the code so it looks nice in the comment?  here it is in a pastebin.  http://pastebin.com/hdiq9k4t

Comment: looks like you're just getting `postData` and `posts` mixed up, but there are other issues there. You're going to have to update the question as the question you've posed has been answered, if you still have problems they are different ones.

Comment: Hi Jack.  I'm not able to create another post for another 90 minutes.  Basically, I think the issue is that on reload, `this.props.posts` is null again for some reason.  That is leading to all these issues.  Since its null, can't use .map(), and I can't even output the title, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` returns an Array, that's why you can do `.map()` on it, which is an Array method. So yeah, you can utilize map on the Array. Literally just call `posts.map(myCallback);`

You're literally taking something where you converted an Object's keys INTO an Array for the purposes of using an Array method on it and asking *"Can I do this to an Array too?"* The answer is *"well...of course, you just don't have to convert it to anything first...just call the Array's .map method"*.

---

You keep saying it says that `postData.map` isn't a function...but you say your Array is named `posts`...so it would be `posts.map`. If whatever you're working with doesn't have a map method, then it's not an Array (at least in modern browsers). Make sure you're calling it on the Array.

Comment: thanks.  can you please check my first post?  i updated with screenshot of console.log(this.props.post)

Comment: @user1354934 - I don't know react (you really should have stated that's what you were dealing with from the start). All I know is that a modern standards compliant JS engine will have a `.map()` method on any Array. If your "Array" doesn't have it then you should be double checking that you're actually referencing an Array in that spot. Keep in mind that `this` can refer to different things depending on the function caller...so check in that spot in the code whether what you're getting is actually the Array you expect or not.